# Interweave two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes `d1` and `d2`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int), list('abc'), [0, 1, 2])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, 2), dtype=int), list('abc'), [3, 4])
```

---

```
d1

   0  1  2
a  1  1  1
b  1  1  1
c  1  1  1
```

---

```
d2

   3  4
a  0  0
b  0  0
c  0  0
```

---

What is an easy and generalized way to interweave two dataframes' columns.  We can assume that the number of columns in `d2` is always one less than the number of columns in `d1`.  And, the indices are the same.

I want this:

```
pd.concat([d1[0], d2[3], d1[1], d2[4], d1[2]], axis=1)

   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to combine the DataFrames, and [`toolz.interleave`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.interleave) reorder the columns:

```
from toolz import interleave

pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)[list(interleave([d1, d2]))]
```

The resulting output is as expected:

```
   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Brilliant as always... I already started using `cytoolz` on your recommendation (-:

Comment: This answer almost felt like cheating, since the `interleave` function is tailor-made for the operation in question.  Yeah, I'm a big fan `toolz`/`cytoolz`.  I remember being happy seeing you use `cytoolz` in one of your questions a little while back!

Comment: Hello, i'm using this solution but i'm getting duplicated columns. Any idea how can i handle?

Answer (score 7):

Here's one NumPy approach -

```
def numpy_interweave(d1, d2):
    c1 = list(d1.columns)
    c2 = list(d2.columns)
    N = (len(c1)+len(c2))
    cols = [None]*N
    cols[::2] = c1
    cols[1::2] = c2

    out_dtype = np.result_type(d1.values.dtype, d2.values.dtype)
    out = np.empty((d1.shape[0],N),dtype=out_dtype)
    out[:,::2] = d1.values
    out[:,1::2] = d2.values

    df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=cols, index=d1.index)
    return df_out
```

Sample run -

```
In [346]: d1
Out[346]: 
   x  y  z
a  6  7  4
b  3  5  6
c  4  6  2

In [347]: d2
Out[347]: 
   p  q
a  4  2
b  7  7
c  7  2

In [348]: numpy_interweave(d1, d2)
Out[348]: 
   x  p  y  q  z
a  6  4  7  2  4
b  3  7  5  7  6
c  4  7  6  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks! This method worked well in our project with Pandas 1.0.5 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 6):

Interweave the columns:

```
c = np.empty((d1.columns.size + d2.columns.size,), dtype=object)
c[0::2], c[1::2] = d1.columns, d2.columns
```

Now, do a join and re-order with boolean indexing:

```
d1.join(d2)[c]

   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

You may prefer `pd.concat` when dealing with multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

write a function to abstract away the generic merge-reorder

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def weave(df1, df2):
  col1 = df1.columns
  col2 = df2.columns
  weaved =  [col for zipped in zip_longest(col1,col2) 
                 for col in zipped
                 if col is not None]
  return pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)[weaved]

weave(d1, d2)
# Output:
   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
In [75]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [76]: cols = pd.Series(np.concatenate(list(zip_longest(d1.columns, d2.columns)))).dropna()

In [77]: cols
Out[77]:
0    0
1    3
2    1
3    4
4    2
dtype: object

In [78]: df = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)[cols]

In [79]: df
Out[79]:
   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use `pd.DataFrame.insert` making sure to insert from the back first

```
df = d1.copy()
for i in range(d2.shape[1], 0, -1):
    df.insert(i, d2.columns[i - 1], d2.iloc[:, i - 1])

df

   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `roundrobin` itertools recipe has an interleaving characteristic.  This option offers the choice between directly implementing the recipe from the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), or importing a third-party package such as [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin) that implements the recipe for you:

```
from more_itertools import roundrobin

pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)[list(roundrobin(d1, d2))]

# Output
   0  3  1  4  2
a  1  0  1  0  1
b  1  0  1  0  1
c  1  0  1  0  1
```

Inspired by @root's answer, the column indices are interleaved and used to slice a concatenated DataFrame.