# How to insert n DataFrame to another every nth row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have an `DataFrame A` as following

```
A
0
1
2
```

Now I want to insert every 2 rows in `DataFrame B` into `A` every 1 row and `B` is as following

```
B
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

finally I want

```
A
0
3
3
1
4
4
2
5
5
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to take each dataframe's values, reshape, concatenate with `np.hstack` and then assign to a new dataframe.

```
In [533]: pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((df1.A.values.reshape(-1, 1),\
                                  df2.B.values.reshape(-1, 2))).reshape(-1, ),\
                       columns=['A'])
Out[533]: 
   A
0  0
1  3
2  3
3  1
4  4
5  4
6  2
7  5
8  5
```

---

Another solution with `pd.concat` and `df.stack`:

```
In [622]: pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df1.A, pd.DataFrame(df2.B.values.reshape(-1, 2))], axis=1)\
                             .stack().reset_index(drop=True),\
                      columns=['A'])
Out[622]: 
   A
0  0
1  3
2  3
3  1
4  4
5  4
6  2
7  5
8  5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there some built-in method in Pandas can do this?

Comment: @danche What you want is pretty niche. There exists `pd.concat` but it cannot interweave series arbitrarily.

Comment: Or maybe can think about `reset_index`

Comment: @Wen Is it possible?

Comment: I am trying it~

Comment: @Wen I found a solution with `df.stack` and reset index... did you mean this?

Comment: If you can share that , it will be much appreciated ~

Comment: @danche Added a pandas method. If it works for you, please consider marking accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I made a mistake in the previous comment , `reset_index` should not work

Comment: @Wen and COLDSPEED Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer +1 (-:

Answer (score 4):

**Setup**
Consider the dataframes `a` and `b`

```
a = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(3)))
b = pd.DataFrame(dict(B=np.arange(3).repeat(2) + 3))
```

**Solution**
Use `interleave` from `toolz` or `cytoolz`
The trick is to split `b` into two arguments of `interleave`

```
from cytoolz import interleave

pd.Series(list(interleave([a.A, b.B[::2], b.B[1::2]])))

0    0
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    4
5    4
6    2
7    5
8    5
dtype: int64
```

---

This is a modification of [**@root's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333133/2336654) to [**my question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45332960/2336654)

Comment: Ah cytoolz again.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this one ?

```
A=len(df1)+len(df2)
df1.index=(list(range(0, A,3)))
df2.index=list(set(range(0, A))-set(range(0, A,3)))
df2.columns=['A']
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).sort_index()

df
Out[188]: 
   A
0  0
1  3
2  3
3  1
4  4
5  4
6  2
7  5
8  5
```

Comment: Nice and inventive!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  Thank you ~ But it is not neat...,still your answer is much better ~

Comment: Nice answer +1 (-:

Comment: @piRSquared your is better ~

Answer (score 0):

If we first split a to len(a) arrays and b to len(b) two arrays we can zip them together, stack and concatenate.

```
a = np.split(dfa.A.values,len(dfa.A))
b = np.split(dfb.B.values,len(dfb.B)/2)

c = np.concatenate(np.hstack(list(zip(a,b))))

pd.Series(c)
```

Returns:

```
0    0
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    4
5    4
6    2
7    5
8    5
dtype: int64
```