# Concatinating the dataframe in pandas so that the indexes are placed one after the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes created using pandas, I want to concatenate them so that the indexes of the two come one after the other. For example,

df1:

```
    x    y
a   10   30
b   20   40
```

df2:

```
    x    y
a1  11   31
b1  21   41
```

required output:

```
    x    y
a   10   30
a1  11   31
b   20   40
b1  21   41
```

Comment: Should the indexes always alternate? What if there is a different amount in each df?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Interleave / Zip two DataFrames by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565311/pandas-interleave-zip-two-dataframes-by-row)

Comment: I will try with the zip_logest() method once. See if that works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the two dataframes and then sort the indeces:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
     x   y
a   10  30
a1  11  31
b   20  40
b1  21  41
```

Comment: ok. sort_index() after concat() works. The output is just how I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can also accept answers if you find them helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Note that this only works if you have specific indices in both input dataframes, for arbitrary keys this won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a counter ("order"), [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and use a stable sorting to reorder in an alternating way with the `sort='stable'` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (pd
   .concat([df1.assign(order=range(len(df1))),
            df2.assign(order=range(len(df2)))])
   .sort_values(by='order', kind='stable')
   .drop(columns='order')
)
```

*NB. this works independently of the length of the two dataframes and the original order of the indices.*

Output:

```
     x   y
a   10  30
a1  11  31
b   20  40
b1  21  41
```

Intermediate after `concat`:

```
     x   y  order
a   10  30      0
b   20  40      1
a1  11  31      0
b1  21  41      1
```

Comment: That's really intuitive. +1. Shouldn't `df2.assign(order=range(len(df1)))` be `df2.assign(order=range(len(df2)))`?