# Interweave a dataframe with 0-columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data:

```
   A    B
0  a    d
1  b  NaN
2  c    c
3  d    f
```

How might I interleave 0-columns between A and B? I'd like to get:

```
   A  X    B
0  a  0    d
1  b  0  NaN
2  c  0    c
3  d  0    f
```

Similarly, for this:

```
   A    B   C
0  a    d   e
1  b  NaN   a
2  c    c   f
3  d    f   g
```

I'd like:

```
   A  X    B    X    C
0  a  0    d    0    e
1  b  0  NaN    0    a
2  c  0    c    0    f
3  d  0    f    0    g
```

How can I do this?

You can find my attempt at this below. I'd like to know other, possibly shorter/more efficient/eccentric ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 0**

```
df.reindex_axis([x for y in lst for x in [y, 'X']][:-1], 1, fill_value=0)

   A  X    B  X  C
0  a  0    d  0  e
1  b  0  NaN  0  a
2  c  0    c  0  f
3  d  0    f  0  g
```

---

**Option 1**
String hackery
Actually, @John Galt beat me to this one.

```
df.reindex_axis('|X|'.join(df).split('|'), 1, fill_value=0)

   A  X    B  X  C
0  a  0    d  0  e
1  b  0  NaN  0  a
2  c  0    c  0  f
3  d  0    f  0  g
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `cytoolz.interleave`
Learned from **@root** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333133/2336654)

```
from cytoolz import interleave

df.reindex(
    columns=list(interleave([df, list('X' * (df.shape[1] - 1))])),
    fill_value=0)

   A  X    B  X  C
0  a  0    d  0  e
1  b  0  NaN  0  a
2  c  0    c  0  f
3  d  0    f  0  g
```

Comment: It's a hack and @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is the OP so he's smart enough to figure it out (-:

Answer (score 4):

**1)** One way to construct columns

```
In [916]: df.reindex(columns=sum([[c, 'X'] for c in df.columns], [])[:-1], fill_value=0)
Out[916]:
   A  X    B  X  C
0  a  0    d  0  e
1  b  0  NaN  0  a
2  c  0    c  0  f
3  d  0    f  0  g

In [917]: sum([[c, 'X'] for c in df.columns], [])[:-1]
Out[917]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'C']
```

**2)** Another way to construct

```
In [924]: def mixcols(cols):
     ...:     ncols = ['X'] * 2 * len(cols)
     ...:     ncols[0::2] = cols
     ...:     return ncols[:-1]

In [925]: mixcols(df.columns)
Out[925]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'C']

In [926]: df.reindex(columns=mixcols(df.columns), fill_value=0)
Out[926]:
   A  X    B  X  C
0  a  0    d  0  e
1  b  0  NaN  0  a
2  c  0    c  0  f
3  d  0    f  0  g
```

**3)** Inspired from @piR

```
In [944]: [c for cx in zip(df.columns, ['X']*len(df.columns)*2) for c in cx][:-1]
Out[944]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'C']
```

Also,

```
In [939]: from itertools import chain, izip

In [940]: list(chain.from_iterable(izip(df.columns, ['X']*len(df.columns)*2)))[:-1]
Out[940]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'C']
```

**4)** Not recommended way

```
In [935]: '-|-X-|-'.join(df.columns).split('-|-')
Out[935]: ['A', 'X', 'B', 'X', 'C']
```

Comment: Why is `4)` not a recommended way?

Comment: If you can guarantee existing column names don't contain split delim `-|-` then, it's okay, but you can't always so.

Comment: TBH +1 is for the 4th option.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at a solution with `df.reindex`:

```
def foo(cols):
     yield cols[0]
     for c in cols[1:]:
         yield from ('X', c)

df1.reindex(columns=foo(df1.columns), fill_value=0)

   A  X    B
0  a  0    d
1  b  0  NaN
2  c  0    c
3  d  0    f
```